# Thematic map exported using QGIS2Web is extremely laggy

Tags: qgis, leaflet, openlayers, qgis2web

I have made a world thematic map and added layers of data for creating graduated color scheme on the country level. I need a interactive map as an output which shows values when user hover over any country.

So while I am exporting it in **Leaflet** format using **QGIS2web** it is not working properly with an **extreme lag**. Also my data is not that big (final output is only 2.5 MB's and only around 500 features in total).

So is there anyway I can remove this lag in the Leaflet format, as the other format (OpenLayers 3) cannot be used as it is not showing legends which are a must for this map?

Comment: Can you upload your map?

Comment: I am not allowed to upload the map from my company resources. Can you help me without the map.

Comment: I have used TM world borders map and used a data with 3 integer columns to make 4 layers of graduated color range based on quantiles. I am taking all these layers and exporting it with leaflet as I require legends

Comment: Link to the maps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4gxlt8OsAI0TGROVWR2bF94U1U/view?usp=docslist_api

Comment: I'm on Windows, and the map seems to load fine in Chrome and Firefox (though the position of the popup is incorrect). However, the map will not load in IE11, and I don't know why. Which OS/browser are you using?

Comment: I have access to only IE and firefox, so it was working fine on firefox with a little lag, but open layers 3 version was flawless.

Comment: But there is another problem with the maps, I cannot choose the last layer without choosing the second layer.